# is there a way to improve the speed of the ODBC connection between sql server and DB2?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I ran this query on my sql server

```
SELECT A.[STCOMP]
    ,A.[STDATE]
    ,A.[STUNM]
    ,A.[STQTY]
    ,A.[STWWAY]
    ,A.[STVOID]
    ,A.[STMATR]
    ,A.[STTCKT]
    ,C.[RWDESC]
    ,A.[STDESC]
    ,A.[STLNDF]
    ,B.[CSLNAM]
    ,B.[CBLNAM]
    ,D.[CVAR6]
FROM [EPAK].[B00BF4CR].[IWSE4S8].[SCTRN] AS A
INNER JOIN [EPAK].[B00BF4CR].[IWSE4S8].[CUST] AS B ON A.[STNCST] = B.[CMSTC#]
    AND A.[STNCMP] = B.[CMSTCO]
    AND A.[STCOMP] = B.[CCMPNY]
    AND A.[STCUST] = B.[CCUST#]
INNER JOIN [EPAK].[B00BF4CR].[IWSE4S8].[SCRWC] AS C ON C.[RWRESW] = A.[STRWC]
    AND C.[RWCOMP] = A.[STCOMP]
INNER JOIN [EPAK].[B00BF4CR].[IWSE4S8].[CUSX] AS D ON A.[STCOMP] = D.[CCMPNY]
    AND A.[STCUST] = D.[CCUST#]
WHERE (
        A.[STDATE] = 20140211
        AND A.[STVOID] = 'N'
        )
ORDER BY A.[STTCKT]
```

the data is for one day only, it returned me 3000 records, but took 52 minutes to do that.
That query is pulling data between a linked DB2 server using odbc connection and my sql.

Comment: It's not clear from the SQL if all the tables are remote - they look it which which case the entire query should be sent remote and not executed locally. If it is split between remote and local then you need to consider which server is to perform the joins - there is a little known hint for all joins, REMOTE, e.g. INNER REMOTE JOIN - which specifies to perform the join remotely - so you can deliberately send the smaller side of the join to the larger side.

Comment: I did what you suggested me and I got this message Msg 7376, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Could not enforce the remote join hint for this query. and when I doubled clic there it highlight select A.[STCOMP], A.[STDATE],A.[STUNM],A.[STQTY],A.[STWWAY],A.[STVOID],A.[STMATR],A.[STTCKT],C.[RWDESC],A.[STDESC],

Comment: It appears these are all remote tables. Try bringing the data into local #Temp tables (limiting where you can) and then query those.

Comment: Actually this is what I am trying to do, I am going to create a temporary table with that query to then with the that data run an stored procedure that will be used in crystal reports

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a view in DB2 in which includes all the joins and selections.

You then simply query this view over the ODBC connection.

The problem is that the ODBC link is very slow, and, returns one row at a time. 
You should do everything you can to minimize the amount of data that is sent over the link.